# Should I learn Aura first and then LWC or should jump to LWC directly?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, apex

I am a SF developer with more than 4 yrs of experience with good hands-on on Apex/configuration.
I have worked on Aura components but still there is still a lot for me to learn in Aura or frontend development.
Instead of learning aura further, should I start learning LWC?

Since I am looking for a job change, they will definitely expect me to be a good Aura/lightning developer. So, should I explore more aura library or should I start with LWC?

Thanks

Comment: IMO having a basic knowledge of aura is sufficient so you can go for LWC directly.

Comment: OPINION based: You can go to LWC, there are some features which would require a use of AURA so you should be able realize when that happens. Also depending on the project if you are from an IT services company, you may need to work with AURA  (or event VF for legacy orgs). So, I would say read about AURA using trailheads to gain basic knowledge.

Comment: In my opinion, you should start learning LWC. During the interviews, you can say like I have worked on Aura and learned LWC on my own. Because it will put a good impression on the interviewer that you are learning new stuff and LWC is a future. Also, be prepared with Aura until you get comfortable with LWC.

Answer (score 5):

There is an extent to which this question is opinion-based or subject to your specific context, but I think there is a clear, general answer *before* adjusting for your specific circumstances:

Learn LWC and forget about Aura, excepting only the few and shrinking situations where Aura is specifically required. LWC is unambiguously the current, supported, actively developed UI framework. Aura is legacy. Any new UI that can be built in LWC should be built in LWC.

Comment: I mostly agree, though I think one should be familiar with Aura to the extent it can be read, mostly because there will be times when one needs to maintain an Aura component, fix bugs, or port it from Aura to LWC. All new development should ideally be in LWC, so that should be one's main strength.